# Django: I want to auto-input field "id" for Many-to-Many tables

Tags: django, python-3.x

I got a `ValueError` while trying to add model instances with a `many-to-many` relationship.

```sh
ValueError: "(Idea: hey)" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

A lot of responses were given here, but none was helpful.
**My (idea) solution was to "manually" input the "id" values.**

```sh
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
>>> from myapp1.models import Category, Idea
# Notice that I manually add an "id"
>>> id2=Idea.objects.create(
...     title_en='tre',
...     subtitle_en='ca',
...     description_en='mata',
...     id=5,
...     is_original=True,
... )
>>> id2.save()
>>> cat22=Category(title_en='yo')
>>> cat22.save()
>>> id2.categories.add(cat22)
>>> Idea.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Idea: tre>]>
>>> exit()
```

**How do i command `django` to auto-add the "id" field?**
Note: I tried adding `autoField` but failed, thanks

```py
   @python_2_unicode_compatible
   class Idea(UrlMixin, CreationModificationDateMixin, MetaTagsMixin):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,)
        title = MultilingualCharField(_("Title"), max_length=200,)
        subtitle = MultilingualCharField(_("Subtitle"), max_length=200, blank=True,)
        description = MultilingualTextField(_("Description"), blank=True,)
        is_original = models.BooleanField(_("Original"), default=False,)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,
```

Comment: Show us your model `Idea`. You normally don't have to add any primary key field to a model, Django automatically adds an `id` field and automatically populates it, like you did with `Category` where you didn't have to add an id to save it.

Comment: The error was telling you that you needed to save the Idea object before adding it to a many-to-many. You've done that in the code above, there was no need to add the ID manually. You should show the *failing* code.

Comment: I am aware that without explicitly declaring an "id" field, django automatically adds it. And that is what i had originally done. But I kept getting that error when trying to call .save()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two things here:

- With many-to-many relationships, when connecting two objects, both objects must already be saved to the database (have a primary key), because under the hoods, Django creates a third object that points at the two objects to connect them. It can only do that if both have an `id`, assuming `id` is the primary key.
- When creating an object, you don't have to explicitly set the `id` (actually you shouldn't). By default, a django `Model` will have `id` set as an auto field and as a primary key (you can override that by specifying your own pk, but in general there's no need to). The `id` is automatically created when the model is saved the first time.

You saw the error because probably one of the objects (idea or category) wasn't saved to the database before you connected them. In your code sample, you don't have to pass `id=5`, it will work without it, because you save `id2` and `category` before connecting them.

Comment: For one reason or another, i tried as much as possible to ignore the "id" field but that error persisted. Even when i tried the same via the django admin GUI

Comment: That's not possible. The code you're showing above works without `id=5`. Unless your model is defined in a strange way. Which is why I asked you to show your model code.